# Get Number of Months and Days Between Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

In PL/SQL I have 2 dates and I need to find out the number of months between them and the days as well. For example date 1 is 1/10/2022 and date 2 is 2/12/2022 that would be 1 month and 2 days. I'm pretty secure in obtaining the number of months, but the days number has been a thorn in my side. Sometimes it comes out correct, sometimes it comes out short and other times it comes out too far. I would imagine it is because of the different number of days in the months, but I can't prove that just yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check - https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2133954/how-to-get-date-difference-in-terms-of-years-months-and-days

Comment: The problem does not make sense (logically, this has nothing to do with "programming"). You need to give your own definition of "number of months and days between two dates". Giving one example is not enough; you must cover all possible cases. For example: is 30 April to 30 May of the same year "one month" or "thirty days"? If you say "one month", then what is 30 April to 31 May - also "one month"? Or is it "one month and one day"? NOTE: You shouldn't use ""your"" definition; rather, whoever asked you for a solution (the "business user") should tell you what **they** mean.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - Much better resource (on the same forum): https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4280566/difference-between-two-dates-in-oralce-sql/p1  One should not stop with the "accepted answer", but rather see the much longer discussion that followed after that. Several (mutually exclusive) interpretations of the problem are discussed, including SQL code to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a months_between function to do the calculation.

That isn't a good idea as the number of days in a month varies, it's not exactly known what the decimal part of the number represents.

```
 select months_between(date '2022-04-03', date '2022-01-01') from dual;

MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE'2022-04-03',DATE'2022-01-01')

3.06451612903225806451612903225806451613
```

If you assume  every month has 30 days, then comparisons over larger date ranges (years) will be out by more and more days the larger the difference gets.

However, if you combine methods, using months_between to get the months, and then assume 30 days for a month to get the days part from the remainder, it's more consistent over longer periods…

```
  with dates as (select date '2022-01-01' as date_from, date '2022-04-03' as date_to from dual)
    select months_between(date_to, date_from)        ,trunc(months_between(date_to, date_from)) as months        ,round(mod(months_between(date_to, date_from),1)*30) as days
   from dates

MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE_TO,DATE_FROM)    MONTHS    DAYS
3.06451612903225806451612903225806451613    3    2
```

Comment: "It's not exactly known what the decimal part represents"? Did you look at the documentation before making such a statement? The documentation says exactly what the decimal part represents, and it's not hard to understand.